# Raspberry Pi 3 hardware acceleration with python bindings

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc, hardware-acceleration, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to make something like mediacenter which will play and stream video. For this I'm trying to use VLC Python bindings library:
https://wiki.videolan.org/python_bindings

I enabled hardware acceleration on the Pi following [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=59814) guide
and it works just fine when I load a video in VLC with the '`--vout omxil_vout`' parameter.

However, when I try to load the same from the Python bindings using `vlc.Instance("--vout=omxil_vout")` it doesn't select the right output and the video is sluggish.

Anybody has any idea as to what I could have done wrong?

Comment: Does `vlc.Instance('--vout omxil_vout')` work?

Comment: Gives the same result

Comment: Sorry but the only clue I can give is to use [OMXPlayer](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer) where you can do: `omxplayer -o hdmi $url`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the replies though. Is it also possible with OMXPlayer to control it via python? Like stopping and changing volume?

Comment: Yes, there is a [Python OMXPlayer wrapper](https://github.com/willprice/python-omxplayer-wrapper) but I did not try it.

Comment: Was looking at that, but it seems to be python 2 only for now, I'm using python 3 =/

Comment: @JanKorf I'm curious to know, did you finally find a way to enable hardware acceleration with the `omxil_vout` while interfacing via the python bindings?

Comment: @JanKorf I just noticed that the linked Python wrapper for OMXPlayer now has support for Python upto version 3.6. So this likely makes my question redundant.

Comment: It's been a while since I made it, but I managed to get it working with the following params: `vlc.Instance("vlc -V omxil_vout --codec omxil")`